# getting bordering US states (php)

Tags: php, geocoding

HI need to be able to select a state and be given a list of the bordering states.  Does anyone have or know of code already done for this?

If I have to write it myself, what would be the best way - possibly a mysql database of borders (two state columns for each row), and then select matching?

EDIT: here's a start - list of borders: http://www.econ.umn.edu/~holmes/data/BORDLIST.html

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
$borders = array (
  'AL' => 
  array (
    0 => 'FL',
    1 => 'GA',
    2 => 'MS',
    3 => 'TN',
  ),
  'FL' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AL',
    1 => 'GA',
  ),
  'GA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AL',
    1 => 'FL',
    2 => 'NC',
    3 => 'SC',
    4 => 'TN',
  ),
  'MS' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AL',
    1 => 'AR',
    2 => 'LA',
    3 => 'TN',
  ),
  'TN' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AL',
    1 => 'AR',
    2 => 'GA',
    3 => 'KY',
    4 => 'MO',
    5 => 'MS',
    6 => 'NC',
    7 => 'VA',
  ),
  'AR' => 
  array (
    0 => 'LA',
    1 => 'MO',
    2 => 'MS',
    3 => 'OK',
    4 => 'TN',
    5 => 'TX',
  ),
  'LA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AR',
    1 => 'MS',
    2 => 'TX',
  ),
  'MO' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AR',
    1 => 'IA',
    2 => 'IL',
    3 => 'KS',
    4 => 'KY',
    5 => 'NE',
    6 => 'OK',
    7 => 'TN',
  ),
  'OK' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AR',
    1 => 'CO',
    2 => 'KS',
    3 => 'MO',
    4 => 'NM',
    5 => 'TX',
  ),
  'TX' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AR',
    1 => 'LA',
    2 => 'NM',
    3 => 'OK',
  ),
  'AZ' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CA',
    1 => 'CO',
    2 => 'NM',
    3 => 'NV',
    4 => 'UT',
  ),
  'CA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AZ',
    1 => 'NV',
    2 => 'OR',
  ),
  'CO' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AZ',
    1 => 'KS',
    2 => 'NE',
    3 => 'NM',
    4 => 'OK',
    5 => 'UT',
    6 => 'WY',
  ),
  'NM' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AZ',
    1 => 'CO',
    2 => 'OK',
    3 => 'TX',
    4 => 'UT',
  ),
  'NV' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AZ',
    1 => 'CA',
    2 => 'ID',
    3 => 'OR',
    4 => 'UT',
  ),
  'UT' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AZ',
    1 => 'CO',
    2 => 'ID',
    3 => 'NM',
    4 => 'NV',
    5 => 'WY',
  ),
  'OR' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CA',
    1 => 'ID',
    2 => 'NV',
    3 => 'WA',
  ),
  'KS' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CO',
    1 => 'MO',
    2 => 'NE',
    3 => 'OK',
  ),
  'NE' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CO',
    1 => 'IA',
    2 => 'KS',
    3 => 'MO',
    4 => 'SD',
    5 => 'WY',
  ),
  'WY' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CO',
    1 => 'ID',
    2 => 'MT',
    3 => 'NE',
    4 => 'SD',
    5 => 'UT',
  ),
  'CT' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MA',
    1 => 'NY',
    2 => 'RI',
  ),
  'MA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CT',
    1 => 'NH',
    2 => 'NY',
    3 => 'RI',
    4 => 'VT',
  ),
  'NY' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CT',
    1 => 'MA',
    2 => 'NJ',
    3 => 'PA',
    4 => 'VT',
  ),
  'RI' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CT',
    1 => 'MA',
  ),
  'DC' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MD',
    1 => 'VA',
  ),
  'MD' => 
  array (
    0 => 'DC',
    1 => 'DE',
    2 => 'PA',
    3 => 'VA',
    4 => 'WV',
  ),
  'VA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'DC',
    1 => 'KY',
    2 => 'MD',
    3 => 'NC',
    4 => 'TN',
    5 => 'WV',
  ),
  'DE' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MD',
    1 => 'NJ',
    2 => 'PA',
  ),
  'NJ' => 
  array (
    0 => 'DE',
    1 => 'NY',
    2 => 'PA',
  ),
  'PA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'DE',
    1 => 'MD',
    2 => 'NJ',
    3 => 'NY',
    4 => 'OH',
    5 => 'WV',
  ),
  'NC' => 
  array (
    0 => 'GA',
    1 => 'SC',
    2 => 'TN',
    3 => 'VA',
  ),
  'SC' => 
  array (
    0 => 'GA',
    1 => 'NC',
  ),
  'IA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MN',
    1 => 'MO',
    2 => 'NE',
    3 => 'SD',
    4 => 'WI',
    5 => 'IL',
  ),
  'MN' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IA',
    1 => 'ND',
    2 => 'SD',
    3 => 'WI',
  ),
  'SD' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IA',
    1 => 'MN',
    2 => 'MT',
    3 => 'ND',
    4 => 'NE',
    5 => 'WY',
  ),
  'WI' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IA',
    1 => 'IL',
    2 => 'MI',
    3 => 'MN',
  ),
  'ID' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MT',
    1 => 'NV',
    2 => 'OR',
    3 => 'UT',
    4 => 'WA',
    5 => 'WY',
  ),
  'MT' => 
  array (
    0 => 'ID',
    1 => 'ND',
    2 => 'SD',
    3 => 'WY',
  ),
  'WA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'ID',
    1 => 'OR',
  ),
  'IL' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IA',
    1 => 'IN',
    2 => 'KY',
    3 => 'MO',
    4 => 'WI',
  ),
  'IN' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IL',
    1 => 'KY',
    2 => 'MI',
    3 => 'OH',
  ),
  'KY' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IL',
    1 => 'IN',
    2 => 'MO',
    3 => 'OH',
    4 => 'TN',
    5 => 'VA',
    6 => 'WV',
  ),
  'MI' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IN',
    1 => 'OH',
    2 => 'WI',
  ),
  'OH' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IN',
    1 => 'KY',
    2 => 'MI',
    3 => 'PA',
    4 => 'WV',
  ),
  'WV' => 
  array (
    0 => 'KY',
    1 => 'MD',
    2 => 'OH',
    3 => 'PA',
    4 => 'VA',
  ),
  'NH' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MA',
    1 => 'ME',
    2 => 'VT',
  ),
  'VT' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MA',
    1 => 'NH',
    2 => 'NY',
  ),
  'ME' => 
  array (
    0 => 'NH',
  ),
  'ND' => 
  array (
    0 => 'MN',
    1 => 'MT',
    2 => 'SD',
  ),
);

echo "Illinois borders: \n";
foreach ($borders['IL'] as $s)
  echo "\t$s\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many combinatorial data sets, this one has a time/space trade off.

If you use the A isNextTo B relation, you have a relation that folds on the diagonal, ie, B is also NextTo A.

Hence the full enumeration is twice as big as it needs to be.

However, if you use only half of the relation you will have to search it both ways: A isNextTo X or X isNextTo A.

And keeping this in  an SQL database will double the storage again as the index needed to search the data will be the same size as the data, so why bother?

PHP doesn't have native b-trees so perhaps PhpClasses.org's btree class would be of interest so you only have to have the data loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

With the list you provide, I would say it's already pretty easy. I would convert the list into a PHP array like so:

```
$borders = 
 array("AL-FL",
       "AL-GA",
 ...
 );
```

then, a primitive (but workable) example for a querying function:

```
/**
 * @desc Returns an array with the bordering states for a state. 
 * @param string the 2-letter code of the state. Case insensitive. Example: AK
 * @param array the list of borders.
 * @return an array with the 2-letter codes of all neighboring states.
 */

function getBorderingStates($state, $borders)
 {
   $neighbors = array(); 
   $state = strtolower($state);

   foreach ($borders as $border)
    {
      $pair = explode("-", $border)
      if (strtolower($pair[0]) == $state) 
        array_push($neighbors, $pair[1]);

      if (strtolower($pair[1]) == $state) 
        array_push($neighbors, $pair[0]);

     }
     return $neighbors;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to write it yourself. Yahoo has a nice geolocation api called WOEID that not only records locations and general Geo-data, but relationships aswell; http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html#relationships

Answer (score 0):

I mapped this all out in a MySQL DB ([DOWNLOAD HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/?3itanbjwtwqc9tm)). It has lat and long as well as state name and abbreviation.

This would be an example of how you would query use this table to query by state, abbrev, and neighboring:

```
#Find state by abbrev
SELECT * FROM states WHERE abbrev = "WA" LIMIT 1;

#Find state by name
SELECT * FROM states WHERE name = "Washington" LIMIT 1;

#Find neighboring states simple
SELECT * FROM states WHERE parent_id = 55;

#Find neighboring states expanded
SELECT * FROM states WHERE parent_id = (SELECT id FROM states WHERE `name` = "West Virginia" LIMIT 1);
```

*note the neighboring data here that was used was from the array'd data from the other post.